# Dealing with character arrays in f2py

Tags: python, fortran, f2py

I'm having problems with arrays of characters working properly with f2py. I cannot access the character arrays from python, yet they seem to be properly defined in fortran. Here is an example fortran module called "example.f90"

```
      module mod
        implicit none
        character(len=8) :: a
        character(len=8), dimension(3) :: b
        character(len=8), allocatable, dimension(:) :: c
      contains
        subroutine test
          implicit none
          a = 'hi a'
          b(1) = 'hi b1'
          b(2) = 'hi b2'
          b(3) = 'hi b3'
          allocate(c(3))
          c(1) = 'hi c1'
          c(2) = 'hi c2'
          c(3) = 'hi c3'
          print*,a
          print*,b
          print*,c
        end subroutine
      end module mod
```

I compile the fortran with f2py: `f2py -c example.f90 -m example`. Then I run the python script, example.py:

```
from example import mod
mod.test()
print(mod.a)
print(mod.b)
print(mod.c)
```

The result is

```
 hi a    
 hi b1   hi b2   hi b3   
 hi c1   hi c2   hi c3   
b'hi a    '
b'hi '
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(mod.c)
ValueError: data type must provide an itemsize
```

Fortran seems to have `b` and `c` properly defined, although I can not access either `b` or `c` from python.

What am I doing wrong? Why can't I access `b` or `c` from python? Why does printing `c` return the `ValueError`? Thanks so much for any suggestion.

Comment: I've tried a similar code with just 'character, allocatable :: ..', but it failed with the same error... (although it works for reals etc https://numpy.org/doc/stable/f2py/python-usage.html#allocatable-arrays) Possibly, characters are treated rather exceptional?

Comment: @roygvib, ya accessing reals from python has worked for me too. Even for allocatable arrays.

Comment: Did you find a workable solution to this? I have had to resort to fixed size arrays declared like so, `character*8 :: species(1000)`. Where 1000 exceeds the expected maximum array size. F2PY seems to deal with this OK just fine.

Comment: @tharen I have stopped using F2PY, and now instead use hand-build wrappers with Cython. Anything is possible with this custom approach. Here are examples: https://github.com/Nicholaswogan/fortran-cython-examples